# Regular expression that only leaves the second number

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to make a regular expression that leaves only the second number.

```
{"1"=>"2", "3"=>"6"}
```

For example, that leaves only the numbers:

```
2, 6
```

I tried this:

```
(([0-9]+)[=>]*([0-9]+))
```

Comment: What is `2, 6`? A string? An Array? Why are you using a regular expression? Seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @jvillian it is an array

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with regular expressions? Why are you asking about regular expressions and then accept an answer that doesn't use one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{"1"=>"2", "3"=>"6"}.values
```

will give you:

```
["2", "6"]
```